# MediaStore.getVolumeName(uri) - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing volume name

Tags: android, mediastore, storage-access-framework, android-storage

Using SAF I selected a folder for R/W media files.

For `MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(volumeName)` (29+ API) I need to specify a volume name (it can be a primary storage or external sd card) and then specify relative path using at:

```
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
        relativePath
    )
}
```

For example I have the following URIs (`uriFolder`):

- `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMUSIC` (primary  storage)
- `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/18F0-2D1C%3AMusic` (external sd card)

so basically volume name can be `"external_primary"` (primary built-in storage) or `"18F0-2D1C"` (an external sd card)

I can just parse this string and get volume name:

a) if `"primary"` then it's going to be `"external_primary"` (we also have the following constant `public static final String VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY = "external_primary";` at `MediaStore` class)

b) if it's an external sd card then just get `"18F0-2D1C"` from string.

But there is also the following function: `MediaStore.getVolumeName(uri)` (29+ API)

I thought it would give me the same results instead of parsing the URI path string manually:

`val volumeName = MediaStore.getVolumeName(uriFolder)`

But I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing volume name: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMUSIC
```

Though for `relativePath` I still need to parse URI path string manually to get `"MUSIC"` after `%3A`

So it's quite tricky to work with `MediaStore` and `SAF` together and fully stop using `File` classes

Comment: `uriFolder` ? There is no such variable in your code. Please put it there as we dont know what you do.

Comment: @blackapps `uriFolder` is a `Uri` (I mentioned this in the example) - `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMUSIC` or `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/18F0-2D1C%3AMusic`. We get it from SAF when selecting a folder to get read/write permission at that location

Comment: "so basically volume name can be "external_primary" (primary built-in storage) or "18F0-2D1C" (an external sd card)" -- no. That *happens* to work *right now* for *one `DocumentsProvider`* implementation. There is no requirement for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to give you a `Uri` from that `DocumentsProvider`. And, there is no requirement for that `DocumentsProvider` to supply a volume name in its `Uri`. The same sort of thing holds true for "Though for relativePath I still need to parse URI path string manually to get "MUSIC" after %3A".

Comment: @CommonsWare @CommonsWare so how are we supposed to work with that? Question #1: Or should I drop `MediaStore` and just create media files using `DocumentFile.createFile(mimeType, fileNameNoExt)` instead of `MediaStore` + `ContentResolver.insert(...,...)`? Question #2: will such file (created without `MediaStore`) will be added to `MediaStore` database? Because `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(File)` takes `File`'s path, we can't pass `DocumentProvider`'s Uri with it.

Comment: If your goal of dealing with `MediaStore` was to create media, I would use `DocumentFile.createFile()`. Whether it will get added to the `MediaStore` index automatically will be based upon what document tree the user chooses and whether that is a location that `MediaStore` can index. So, for example, if they choose some encrypted document provider, or some cloud document provider, it will not be part of the `MediaStore` index. But, *that is the user's choice to make*.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. I guess `MediaStore` is not really useful for apps when a user wants to control for example where record video files should be saved with a video recorder app. So we switch from `File` custom browser folder selector to SAF's folder selection and then working only with `DocumentFile`. Especially if such app should have an automatic file deletion (loop recording), so such apps should have write permission for all files in selected folder even after reinstalling the app

Comment: @CommonsWare one issue that if not using `MediaStore` then we can't set Pending status for the media file which was created using `DocumentFile.createFile()` - `val contentValues = ContentValues().apply { put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1) }`, `val uriMediaStore = MediaStore.getMediaUri(context, uriDocumentFile)!!`, `contentResolver.update(uriMediaStore, contentValues, null, null)` - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only owner is able to interact with pending/trashed item content://media/18f0-2d1c/file/1000000455`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaStore.getVolumeName(uri) works only for uris you got from the media store.

Such uries start with content://media/...

MediaStore.getVolumeName(uri): external for: content://media/external/file/1000469026

MediaStore.getVolumeName(uri): 28ef-1de5 for: content://media/28ef-1de5/file/391988

Comment: I see... I was hopping to use `val uriMediaStore = MediaStore.getMediaUri(context, uriSafFolder)` but I guess it works only for media files, not folders

Comment: or I can create file using SAF - `val uriMediaFileSaf = DocumentFile.createFile(mimeType, fileNameNoExt)` and then I can use `val uriMediaStore = MediaStore.getMediaUri(context, uriMediaFileSaf)`, though what's the point in using `MediaStore` then if a media file is created already created :)